# Theme picker for Laravel 8 blogging application

Tags: php, validation, laravel

I am working on a **[blogging application in Laravel 8](https://github.com/Ajax30/BraveCMS-2.0)**.

The application supports themes. In a nutshell, theme support works like this:

In the `views` directory, I have the directory containing the views of every theme.

[image: screenshot of views directory]

In `public\themes` I keep the assets (CSS, Javascript) of every theme.

[image: screenshot of themes directory]

In the *SettingsController controller* I have, among others, a variable named $theme_directory, which contains the name of the directory of the *current theme*. I use this variable in the theme view, like this, for instance:

```
<link href="{{ asset('themes/' . $theme_directory . '/css/clean-blog.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

From the "Settings" section I can set the current theme.

[image: screenshot of form]

I have added a "theme picker": a *select-box containing all the available themes* to pick from.

In the controller, I have a `themes()` method that *reads the names of the themes directories* in the views and displays them:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Dashboard;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Settings;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

class SettingsController extends Controller {
    
    private $rules = [
        'site_name' => 'required|string|max:190',
        'tagline' => 'required|string|max:190',
        'owner_name' => 'required|string|max:190',
        'owner_email' => 'required|email|max:190',
        'twitter' => 'required|string|max:190',
        'facebook' => 'required|string|max:190',
        'instagram' => 'required|string|max:190',
        'theme_directory' => 'required',
    ];

    private $messages = [
        'site_name.required' => 'A site title is required',
        'tagline.required' => 'A site tag line is required',
        'owner_name.required' => 'Please provide a site owner/company name',
        'owner_email.required' => 'A valid email is required',
        'owner_email.email' => 'The email you provided is not valid',
        'twitter.required' => 'Please provide a Twitter account',
        'facebook.required' => 'Please provide a Facebook account',
        'instagram.required' => 'Please provide an Instagram account',
        'theme_directory.required' => 'Please pick a theme',
    ];

    public function themes() {
        $themes = [];
        $themes_path = Config::get('view.paths')[0] . '\themes';
        foreach(File::directories($themes_path) as $theme) {
          $slug = array_reverse(explode('\\', $theme))[0];
          $name = ucwords(str_replace('-', ' ', $slug));
          $themes[] = (object)compact('slug', 'name');
        }
        return $themes;
    }
    
    public function index() {
        $settings = Settings::first();
        return view('dashboard/settings', [
         'settings' => $settings, 
         'themes' => $this->themes()
        ]);
    }

    public function update(Request $request) {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $this->rules, $this->messages);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator->errors())->withInput();
        } else {
            $settings = Settings::first();
            $settings->site_name = $request->get('site_name');
            $settings->tagline = $request->get('tagline');
            $settings->owner_name = $request->get('owner_name');
            $settings->owner_email = $request->get('owner_email');
            $settings->twitter = $request->get('twitter');
            $settings->facebook = $request->get('facebook');
            $settings->instagram = $request->get('instagram');
            $settings->theme_directory = $request->get('theme_directory');
            $settings->is_cookieconsent = $request->get('is_cookieconsent') == 'on' ? 1 : 0;
            $settings->is_infinitescroll = $request->get('is_infinitescroll') == 'on' ? 1 : 0;
            
            $settings->save();
            return redirect()->route('dashboard.settings')->with('success', 'The settings were updated!');
        }
    }
}
```

In the view (form), I have:

```
<div class="row mb-2">
    <label for="theme" class="col-md-12">{{ __('Theme directory') }}</label>
    <div class="col-md-12 @error('theme_directory') has-error @enderror">
        <select name="theme_directory" id="theme" class="form-control @error('theme_directory') is-invalid @enderror">
            <option value="">Pick a theme</option>
            @foreach($themes as $theme)
                <option value="{{ $theme->slug }}" {{ $theme->slug == $settings->theme_directory  ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $theme->name }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>

            @error('theme_directory')
                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                    </span>
            @enderror
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Questions:

1. Is there any redundancy in my code?
2. Do you see any security issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ## *Is there any redundancy in my code?*

### There is some redundancy between `$rules` and `$messages`

This may not be an orthodox idea by many Laravel programmers but `$rules` could be generated on the fly by iterating over the keys of `$messages` - Something like:

```
$rules = array_reduce(array_keys($messages), function($carry, $messageKey) {
    [$field] = explode('.', $messageKey);
    if (str_contains($field, 'theme')) {
        return $carry + [$field => 'required'];
    }
    $type = str_contains($field, 'email') ? 'email' : 'string';
    return $carry + [$field => "required|$type|max:190"];
}, []);
```

### The `update` method repeatedly calls `$request->get()`

That method calls `$request->get()` ten times. Many of those could be called in a loop - e.g. which iterates over the fields from `$messages`.

As I explained in [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/268847/120114) a [subclass of form request](https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#form-request-validation) could be created to encapsulate all of the validation logic and [simplify the setting of validated fields in the model](https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#working-with-validated-input).

If such a form request was made, then most all of those lines calling `$request()->get()` could be replaced with a single call to `$request->validated()` using the [`update()` method](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_update).

---

> ## *Do you see any security issues?*

Can any user update update the settings? If not, then perhaps a role should be checked on the user.

Another benefit of form requests is [that they can help with authorization](https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#authorizing-form-requests) - e.g. the `authorize()` method can be defined and have it return `false` for any user that should not be able to submit such a request.